# tail -f all files in a "living directory"

Tags: linux, directory, tail

I am working with a directory where logs are constantly created. I use tail -f * in bash to view all the log entrys in the dir. However, when new files are created while the tail is running, the new files are not utilized by the tail. Is there a simple solution for that? Thank you!

EDIT: OS: SLES4SAP 12 SP2 3.0.101-63-default

Comment: Ugh, that linked "duplicate" question is terrible. Nowhere does it state that the list of files is changing.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the `tail -f *` command it expands `*` to the files present in the directory in that moment, so when a new file is added to it you won't be able to see it unless you use `tail` again and add the new file to the arguments.

You could use `watch` with `tail` so it's always expanding `*` and if a new file appears it'll be matched.

An example would be `watch -n 1 tail *`, then you can adjust the update interval as you need, depending on the update rate of your log files.

Comment: I wouldn't use `watch` for that, but you're not too far off the right track.   Better would be a shell script that runs `tail -f *` (or one `tail -f` for each file in the directory if you want to be able to stop tailing a file if it is closed or deleted) and then uses `inotify` to monitor the directory.  As new files are created, fork another `tail` for them.  And (optionally) if a file is closed or deleted, kill the corresponding tail process.  Alternatively, a perl script using `File::Tail` and `Linux::Inotify2`.  hmmm...it turns out that the (perl) utility `iWatch` does stuff like that.

Comment: see http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/ (or `apt-get install iwatch` on debian etc)